# How to print a table from lists with different lengths in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.x

How do I print a table from two lists that have varying lengths (each list being a column)?

Example:

```
>>> l1=['Cat', 'Dog', 'Gorilla', 'Ladybug']
>>> l2=['Cat', 'Dog']
>>> print_chart(l1, l2)
Cat        Cat
Dog        Dog
Gorilla
Ladybug
```

Using [rjust](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/pytut/FancierOutputFormatting.html) may be useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`itertools.izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest):

```
for a, b in izip_longest(l1, l2, fillvalue=''):
    print "{0:20s}\t{1:20s}".format(a, b)
```

Comment: +1. I might suggest as kwarg to `izip_longest`: `fillvalue=""` instead. But what you have is quite explicit which is of course the ultimate goal.

Comment: @Adam: I just read the documentation, but it didn't click. Thanks, fixed it.